# Organized and intentional suicide attacks during military conflicts

Tags: military, war, nazi-germany, japan, aircraft

First of all I want to make it clear that we're not speaking about terrorist attacks here. This question is strictly dedicated to war operations, in a [dictionary meaning](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/war).

Also this question is about all the history of military conflicts, not only World War II.

Surely everybody heard about suicide missions of [kamikaze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamikaze), Imperial Japanese Army Air Service suicide plane attacks against American warships during World War II. Around 4000 sacrificed aviators succeeded to destroy at least 47 ships and damage 300 of them. Similar conceptions in the Empire of Japan were [Shinyo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinyo_%28suicide_boat%29) suicide boats, [Kaiten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiten) submarines and [Fukuryu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fukuryu) suicide divers.

But this strategy wasn't used only by Japanese military forces. Also Luftwaffe used it in the closing stage of the war. From 17 April until 20 April 1945 (during the [Battle of Berlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Berlin)) 35 pilots of the [Leonidas Squadron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selbstopfer) flew suicide sorties against bridges at the Oder river, which now is a borderline between Germany and Poland.

I'm also aware of the already asked question [Is there a written history on the Sonderkommando Elbe?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/is-there-a-written-history-on-the-sonderkommando-elbe) regarding the similarities of that Luftwaffe unit, used against American bombers, with the difference that [the aviators were expected to bail out just before colliding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonderkommando_Elbe).

The question is, are there any other examples of organizing intentional suicide attacks in a theater of war?

Comment: I think the scope of the question is difficult.  I think that every "forlorn hope" is within the scope of your question, as is every squad detached to hold a hopless position and grant the rest of the unit time to retreat, and every man who throws himself on a grenade. Some would claim that serving aboard a destroyer is within scope. (According to the Carrier Air Wing, the only purpose for destroyers is to act as floating armor for the carrier).  Much as I hate to admit it, there isn't a clear distinction between  heroism and self-sacrifice.

Comment: Citations please: "This question is strictly dedicated to war, in the most common sense of this word."

Comment: Samuel what do you mean by citations? That I should provide a definition of war from dictionary? I believe it's quite easy to differ war operations from terrorist acts. But I'll do that.

Comment: Mark, I've edited the question to restrict its scope to intentional suicide attacks with use of planes or vehicles. I hope it will be less arguable now.

Comment: As a small comment, if you restrict this to vehicles only, you would have a VERY small window of time, between when the planes or vehicles became powerful enough to be able to do enough mass damage to make the attack worth bothering with and fast enough to make it plausible; and the time where control systems evolved to the point that human controller was no longer necessary for a missile and other weapons became dangerous, powerful and effective enough than a car full of explosives didn't really have much benefit over a rocket battery on a battlefield.

Comment: Very good point. I've deleted this fragment.

Comment: Your "war" is my "civil conflict" is his "terrorist incident".

Comment: It's hard to answer this question, because too many things are borderline. For example, in the Russo-Japanese war, when an officer told  higher commander that further attacks on positions defended by machine guns was useless, he was told that he and his soldiers should go out there and die. Is that a suicide attack? It is in the sense that the only outcome is that the Japanese soldiers die. But it's not a suicide attack in the sense that you use your suicide as a way to kill enemy soldiers. It's more suicide than attack, if you will.

Comment: I strongly recommend that advice from these comments be included back into the Question's scope by OP.  Interesting answers have been given, and the question merits improvement to avoid closing on grounds of policy

Comment: @NewAlexandria which exact advice you mean? The first one, saying "the scope is too wide", that lead me to narrow the scope, or the second one, saying "the scope is too narrow", that would lead me to widen it once again?

Comment: There is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_ramming that isn't necessarily suicidal, but you are unlikely to survive. There was also the M-29 Davy Crockett (nuclear bazooka) that was not necessarily lethal to the user but at short distances would be.

Answer (score 2):

In the struggle for the Pacific Islands, Japanese infantry launched nocturnal "Banzai" bayonet attacks on the Americans that were basically suicidal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banzai_charge In the battle for Okinawa, the "superbattleship" Yamato was given enough fuel for a one-way trip (from Japan), and expected to sink as many American ships has possible, but not return. (She was sunk by American planes before reaching Okinawa.)

At the battle of Masada, the outnumbered and outweaponed Israeli defenders elected to follow a "scorched earth" policy, including taking each others' lives, rather than to surrender to the Romans. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Masada

Comment: Massada was not a suicide attack, the defenders killed each other cleanly and quickly rather than be subjected to torture when inevitably captured and treated as enemies of Rome tended to be treated, which was none too gently. This was done by lot, the last man standing killing himself, thus committing the gravest of sins, putting his soul in peril (not sure how the Torah handles this, but that's the gist of it).

Comment: @jwenting: It wasn't an attack. But it was a military "suicide," which makes it striking in history.

Comment: most of the people involved were civilians, making it even more striking :)

Comment: @jwenting: They drank the Kool-Aid, as others have in the past, and others still will do so again in the future. That's not battle.

Comment: Only two out of three examples mentioned in this answer come with references and they are both "wrong", i.e., they do not answer the question. The one example that sounds right gives no reference.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel:  I have removed the Washington reference. All (remaining) paragraphs now have references. I maintain that Masada is "topical" because "suicide" was an essential element of the Israeli strategy, even if "attack" wasn't. More to the point, the mass suicide was an "attack" on the annals of history, probably making it better remembered than e.g. a Japanese Banzai attack might be.

Comment: Downvote removed. I still very much disagree with including Masada in your answer. Your explanation makes no sense to me. It conflates categories in a way that I find abhorrent. It's a problem that I have with many of your answers.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: Thank you for your consideration. We can continue to "agree to disagree."

Comment: I too think you can't include the Battle of Massada. The Romans were attacking, and the defenders killed themselves after a long siege. That's not a suicide attack.

Comment: @jjack: I would consider it a suicide "attack" insofar as it was an assault on human consciousness. That is, it was a moral attack, not a physical one.

Comment: @TomAu This really is a stretch to the point of being plain wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Shtrafbat were Soviet penal battalions used in the Eastern Front of World War II.

One form of Shtrafbat were tramplers. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtrafbat#.22Trampler.22_mine-clearing_battalions):

> Smaller battalions were established out of the infantry units to clear
>   minefields as 'tramplers' - unarmed men who ran through the minefields
>   ("trampled") ahead of regular assault forces to detonate land mines.
>   The worst of all the penal battalion assignments, the tramplers were
>   prepared for their grisly suicide missions by being heavily fortified
>   with vodka rations by their leaders before attacks. Trampler
>   battalions were assembled from the penal infantry units for major
>   attacks and were usually wiped out to the last man, with their mangled
>   bodies reportedly "marking the safe passage corridor of the late-war
>   Red Army through any minefield".

Technically, tramplers weren't attacking the enemy, but they assisted others attacking the enemy.

A similar tactic was reportedly used by Iran in the Iran-Iraq war. Again, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basij)

> During the Iran-Iraq War hundreds of thousands volunteered for the
>   Basij, including children as young as 12 and unemployed old men, some
>   in their eighties. These volunteers were swept up in Shi'i love of
>   martyrdom and the atmosphere of patriotism of the war mobilization.
>   They were encouraged through visits to the schools and an intensive
>   media campaign. The Basij may best be known for their employment human
>   wave attacks which cleared minefields or draw the enemy's fire. It is
>   estimated that tens of thousands were killed in the process. Some
>   reports have the Basiji marching into battle marking their expected
>   entry to heaven by wearing plastic "keys to paradise" around their
>   necks.

Comment: Also "suicide" but not "suicide attacks". But then, where do you draw the line?

Comment: @LennartRegebro their actions helped obtain a military objective.

Comment: Right, which is why I think the question is problematic, because what is counted as suicide attack is completely subjective, when even non-attacks and non-suicides (see other answers) can be counted. As well, clearly, as murder of unarmed people, which really your first example is about.

Answer (score 2):

It has been said that during the Iran/Iraq war, Iran organized corps of volunteers whose job was to walk through Iraqi minefields and essentially [clear the mines with their own bodies](http://www.matthiaskuentzel.de/contents/ahmadinejads-demons).

I'm not entirely sure how well established that is. However, it is fairly well documented that Iran would organize [human-wave attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_War#Iran_introduces_the_human_wave_attack), which are by their nature essentially suicidal for all but a perhaps a lucky few of the participants.

[Human wave attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_wave_attack) in general are not an uncommon tactic in warfare, though. [The storming of the beaches in Normandy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omaha_Beach#Infantry_landings) was essentially a suicidal endevor for the first wave of units off the boats. The same can easily be said for the Zulu attacks at [Rourke's Drift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Rorke%27s_Drift), the North Vietnamese at [Hill 488](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Hill_488), the torpedo aircraft [attacks on the Japanese fleet at Midway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Midway#Attacks_on_the_Japanese_fleet), or pretty much the first wave of any attack against any fortified position in history.

Comment: Don't confuse the debacle of Omaha Beach with the entirety of D-Day. Canadian casualties on [Juno Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juno_Beach) were less than 1,000 total for the entire day: 340 dead, 574 wounded, 34 captured.

Answer (score 0):

[The Battle of the Long Sault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Long_Sault)

While the historiography gives many conflicting details and claims without sources (Some historians said...), I refer to the writings by contemporary witness [Pierre-Esprit Radisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Esprit_Radisson).

According to him the French settlements got intel from trappers, mountainman and friendly Indians that the Iroquois were preparing one massive assault on the french settlements which were allied with the Hurons and Algonquin. Approximately 1000 warriors were moving in to assault the settlements and burn them to the ground.

Adam Dollard des Ormeaux made the desperate decision to move against the Iroquois with only 17 of voluntary militia. He absolutely knew that it was a suicide mission, but he intended to inflict such heavy losses that the Iroquois would think twice to continue the attack on the settlements which had more weapons and men available. Every volunteer sweared to God that he would not give up and fight until the bitter end. For this reason Dollard had much more muskets and gunpowder than a normal hunting party and also grape shot. The allied Hurons were also an important factor that the numerical superiority was not so overwhelming.

The Wikipedia article is silent why such a small force was capable to hold off 200 Iroquois warriors for several days. The Iroquois were used to ambush the enemy party once they fired their muskets because the reloading time was slow. Their problem was that Dollard had *three* muskets available for each shooter and each shooter had one reloader who was reloading the muskets as fast as possible, so they were able to repel the attacks and inflict heavy losses.
After a backup of 500 warriors arrived and started a human wave attack, the defenders switched to grapeshot and inflicted horrible losses.

While they finally succumbed, Dollard was successful: His strategy inflicted 
such losses that the Iroquois give up to attack the settlements.